# JFET question about operation

Tags: voltage, current, analog, jfet

I have a question about the N-JFET.Assume it operates at the linear region and it acts like a voltage controlled resistor. Can we say that if Vdg(drain-gate voltage) is increased then the resistance of the JFET is increased?I have just started reading about JFET and I find them very confusing.

Also I found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wNiXUZIHQLw) video , I don't understand why most have Vds and Vgs which is very confusing...

Comment: doesn't the drain-gate voltage increase the resistance?

Comment: for  N channel jfet the gate voltage is negative wrt to source, the more negative it is the less current from source to drain

Comment: do you mean a more negative gate-source voltage will increase the source to drain resistance? assuming drain-source voltage is such that if  gate-source voltage varies the device remains in ohmic region?